# Spaces are different in the same sentence/string

Tags: python, format

I have some stuff in an Excel spreadsheet, which is loaded into a webpage, where the content is displayed. However, what I have noticed is, that some of the content has weird formatting, i.e. a sudden line shift or something.

Then I just tried to copy the text from the spreadsheet, and pasting it into Notepad++, and enabled "Show White Space and Tab", and then the output was this:

[image]

The second line is the one directly copied from the spreadsheet, where the first one is just where I copied the string into a variable in Python, printed it, and then copied the output from the output console.

And as you can see the first line has all dots for space, where the other misses some dots. And I have an idea that that is what is doing this trickery, especially because it's at those place the line shift happens.

I have tried to just do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("my_spreadsheet.xlsx")

data["Strings"] = [str(x).replace(" ", " ") for x in data["Strings"]]

data.to_excel("my_spreadsheet.xlsx", index=False)
```

But that didn't change anything, as if I copied it straight from the output console.

So yeah, is there any easy way to make spaces the same type of spaces, or do I have to do something else ?

Comment: Please avoid adding the data as image as we can not copy the content from image, you are expected to add data as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to figure out which exact character is being used there.

You can load the file and print out the characters one by one together with the character code to figure out what's what.

See the code example below. I added some code to skip alphanumeric characters to reduce the actual output somewhat...

```py
with open("filename.txt") as infile:
    text = infile.readlines()

def print_ordinal(text: str, skip_alphanum: bool=True): 
    for line in text:
        for character in line:
            if not(skip_alphanum and character.isalnum()):
                print(f"{character} - {ord(character)}")


print_ordinal(text)
```

Comment: Sorry for not coming back sooner. But this was a good answer. The difference was that one type of space was unicode 32, and the other was unicode 160. So after that it was easy to just replace.